# Free Desktop Application -> Create single PDF from multible HTML Pages with Hyperlinks

Tags: pdf, html

I have a folder called `product manual in html` containing an `manual_index.html` page and several sub pages `manual_introduction.html`, `manual_maintenance.html` and many more sub pages. The folder contains a offline version of an `.html` product manual

All the pages are linked with `<a href="manual_maintenance.htmll"> See the Maintenance page</a>`

I need a free software that i creating me a single `.pdf` file containing all linked files that the user can open the target `.pdf` file and see the    table of contents  click on a content and gets refereed to the target page in the same `.pdf` document.

-It has to be an offline software
-I need that the output `.pdf` file also contains a table of contents

Answer (score 1):

You can probably get it done with [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html), as its description is exactly what you're looking for:

> Pandoc can convert between numerous markup and word processing formats, including, but not limited to, various flavors of Markdown, HTML, LaTeX and Word docx. For the full lists of input and output formats, see the --from and --to options below. Pandoc can also produce PDF output: see creating a PDF, below